Problem about Theorem 3 proof of David L. Donoho's Compressed Sensing
I am dealing with the proof of Theorem 3 of Donoho's paper on compressed sensing. Theorem 3, giving the equilibrium of Gel'fand $n$-width and the optimal error of recontructed signal, is as follows:

Notations (for more detailed interpretation, please go to Section 1 and 2 of the paper):

$X$ is a set of interested objects (for example signals, images and so on), and every $x\in X$ is a $\mathbb{R}^m$ vector. There is an orthogonal basis for $\mathbb{R}^m$, namely $\{\psi_i:i=1,2,...,m\}$. The object $x$ has transform coefficients $\theta_i = \langle x,\psi_i\rangle$ and are assumed sparse, in the sense that for $0<p<2$ and some $R>0$, $\Vert \theta\Vert_p \leqslant R$. Then $X_{p,m}(R) = \{ x:\Vert \theta(x)\Vert_p \leqslant R \}$.

$E_n(X) = \inf\limits_{A_n,I_n} \sup\limits_{x\in X} \{\Vert x-A_n(I_n(x))\Vert_2\}$ indicates the best possible error between reconstructed and original signals, in a sense of taking $\inf$ over all feasible sampling operator $I_n$ and reconstructing algorithm $A_n$. Among this, $I_n:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is the sampling operator satisfying $n<<m$, and $A_n$ is an algorithm recontructing object $x$ from a sampled vector.

$d^n(X)$ is the Gel'fand $n$-width on X with respect to $l_2$ norm, defined as $d^n(X;l_2) = \inf\limits_{V_n} \sup \{ \Vert x \Vert_2: x\in V_n^{\bot}\cap X \}$ .

$\hat{X}_{p,R}(y_n) = \{x: y_n = I_n(x),x\in X_{p,m}(R)\}$. Specially, $\hat{X}_{p,R}(0) = X_{p,m}(R)\cap \ker(I_n)$. The radius of a set $X$ is defined as $radius(X) = \inf\limits_{c} \sup \{ \Vert x-c\Vert_2: x\in X\} $. It is fair to consider the optimal $c$ in this definition as the "center" of the set $X$, but $c$ is not necessarily contained in $X$.


The former part of the proof of this theorem, lying in Section 3 of the paper, is as follows:

Now my question is: the last equation seems not to hold. Because the $d^n$ is the minimax of $\Vert x\Vert_2 = \Vert x-0\Vert_2$, while the radius only deals with the minimax of $\Vert x-c\Vert_2$ for some "center" $c$. Actually I think the former inequality of theorem 3 does not hold (contrastly, the inequality should be reversed) based on the same reason I stated. This paper has been cited for more than 20,000 times, but I still think this equation has to be wrong or something. Can anyone give me a clarification?

If I failed to state something clearly, please feel free to tell me. I am a postgraduate of maths and looking for the application of compressed sensing in my field. I just want to clarify some vague points in this classical paper, and if anyone has more questions about this paper, it is also welcomed to discuss in this post. I think this paper still has something vague in its math languages besides this post.
